# How to write COUNTIFS function in Power Query where 2nd piece of COUNTIF is searching for 7 days ahead of date value

Tags: powerquery

I wrote a COUNTIFS function in Excel to tell me if there is a date a week away from the indexed row date, including one more criteria. The function reads as:

COUNTIFS(Table1_1[Lookup2],Table1_1[@Lookup2],Table1_1[Date],Table1_1[@Date]+7)

where Lookup2 is a helper column and Date is a date

How would I do this in PowerQuery?

I have tried Group By function, but don't know how to add the "+7" days piece to it

| Lookup1 | Date | Result |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC - ALBERTSONSCO ACME - RMABEAR NAKED11 | 1/22/2023 | 1 |  |  |
| AC - ALBERTSONSCO ACME - RMABEAR NAKED11 | 1/29/2023 | 1 |  |  |
| AC - ALBERTSONSCO ACME - RMABEAR NAKED11 | 2/5/2023 | 0 |  |  |

The above is an example - since there is a date 7 days after 1/22/2023, given the Lookup1 criteria, it will return a 1. There is no date within 7 days of 2/5/2023 with Lookup1 criteria, so it returns a 0

Comment: Can you illustrate with a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and demonstrate desired result?

Comment: @pgSystemTester I added some clarity using a mark down table to the question - hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a Custom Column with:

```
Table.RowCount(
  Table.SelectRows(
    PreviousStep, (tbl) => 
      tbl[Lookup1] = [Lookup1] and 
      tbl[Date] > [Date] and 
      tbl[Date] <= Date.AddDays([Date], 7 ) 
  )
)
```

Do update `PreviousStep` with the name of your `#"Previous step"`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sam - I am pretty new to PQ here - what do you mean by update with the name of my previous step?

Comment: On the right pane, under Query Settings, you'll see a list of `APPLIED STEPS`. Update the code above with the name of the last step. https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2rq9.png In this case it would `#"Changed Type"`.

Comment: Oh, okay - that makes sense. And what is the difference between "tbl[Date] and just [Date]?

Comment: `tbl` is an alias to `PreviousStep`, which is the whole table itself, so we are filtering the `PreviousStep` where the column `tbl[Date]` is greater than the current row's `[Date]` value. Where as `[Date]` is the singular value for that row.

Comment: Makes sense - thank you very much for this! It seems to have worked how I would like it to, but just is extremely slow (as I have quite a lot of data)

Comment: It will be slow for a large number of rows, as it will be filtering the table each time. You may consider if this calculation could be added at the data source. Or may be consider creating a measure in DAX that can do this, then it could be dynamic (ie it can change from 7 days, to 14 day etc...)